# Is there a way in Jmeter JDBC request to convert "result variable" data into Json format?

Tags: jmeter, convertto-json

I am storing Jmeter JDBC REquest data in result variable which come out in following format :
[[alt_id:535644, cd:A, cube:1.000, stat_dt:null, ts:9999-12-31T00:01]]

I tried the following to convert it to JSON but not successful :

```
def resl = vars.getObject('jdbc_dcRes');
log.info("Jdbc result : " + resl);
def json = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(resl).toPreetyString();
OR
def json = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(resl).toString();
log.info("Jdbc result Converted into Json : " + json);
```

Getting :
2022-02-11 15:31:51,971 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[dc Service 1-1,6,main]
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putVal(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.putIfAbsent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.getClassLoadingLock(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_111]
at groovy.lang.MetaClassRegistry$MetaClassCreationHandle.createWithCustomLookup(MetaClassRegistry.java:144) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
at groovy.lang.MetaClassRegistry$MetaClassCreationHandle.create(MetaClassRegistry.java:139) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClassUnderLock(ClassInfo.java:272) ~[groovy-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]

.............

Any pointer to overcome this would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the following code snippet works just fine:

```
def resl = vars.getObject('jdbc_dcRes')

def json = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(resl).toPrettyString()

log.info('Jdbc result Converted into Json :' + json)
```

Demo:

[image]

I'm using normal [MySQL database](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) 8.0.28 and the following query:

```
select * from help_category limit 2
```

So you might want to try to replicate the above and if it will be successful - most probably the problem is with the data from your DB which cannot be converted to JSON using Groovy's [JsonBuilder](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html) without extra transformation (i.e. you have specific data types which cannot be mapped 1-to-1 to JSON data types)

See [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter) to learn more about anatomy of the beast called "Result variable name" in JMeter's JDBC Request sampler

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the root cause. DateTime data type in mysql was the culprit. After handling it in the query, the issue got resolved and i got the expected Json .